# Is there a way to prevent anything overflowing out of an html element through automatically resizing children?

Tags: html, css

In the example below, is there a way to **override** the size of the `h1` tags so they do not overflow (**I do not want to just hide the overflow**).

We really want the 'strictContainer' to be 100px of height and not bigger. I searched for **an analoguous to `size:auto`** but found nothing.

```css
h1 {
  height: 80px; border:solid black
}

.strictContainer {
  height: 150px; border:solid gold
}
```

```html
<div class="strictContainer">
  <h1>Hello
    </h1>
    <h1>Hello
    </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot modify the original CSS. You can override the size of `h1` using a new rule make it have more [precedence](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html).
One way to fit both the h1 tags in the container is to make them have equal heights:

```css
/* original rules */

h1 {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black
}

.strictContainer {
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}


/* overrides */

.strictContainer>h1 {
  /* need to override default margins */
  margin: auto 0;
  /* make them have equal heights*/
  height: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* uncomment following to have auto height */
  /*height: auto;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="strictContainer">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

User agents(browsers) put default styles on some html elements. For example, Chrome has following style on h1 tags by default:

```css
h1 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-block-start: 0.67em;
  margin-block-end: 0.67em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

In order to fit both the tags we need to override [margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin). I used `margin: auto 0;`. This means vertical margin is auto and horizontal margin is 0.
We've used `box-sizing: border-box;` to make borders part of the dimensions. Otherwise we would have to calculate height using `height: calc(50% - 4px);`

---

**solution 2** You can make the container a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
/* original rules */

h1 {
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid black
}

.strictContainer {
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}


/* overrides */

.strictContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around; /* play with this */
}

.strictContainer>h1 {
  /* need to override default margins */
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* for 50% height use this */
  /*flex: 1 0 auto;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="strictContainer">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

**Note:** In your code snippet you've used 150px height for the container so I've used the same. If your issue is with margins then you can use

Answer (score 0):

You can use `overflow: hidden` to hide any content that may overflow, but I think you are asking for `height: min-content`.

```css
.container {
  width: 10em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: min-content;
  background: peachpuff; 
}
.content {
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Hello this is some content la la la la la</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Overflow hidden is used to hide element that overflows

```css
overflow:hidden
/**
other values are visible(default),scroll and auto
ww3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp 
**/
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
/*
 you can remove the default setting  
for box-sizing you can check out the following link 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
I highly recommend you to use % or vh/vw instead of px 
It makes your website responsive 
*/
h1 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.strictContainer {
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="strictContainer">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).